# Angularjs limitTo not working when use (key,value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to make a vertical menu from array like this:

```
{"sport":"Soccer","country":"Brazil","Teams":"TeamA vs Teamb"}
```

So I need group it by `sport`, next by `country`, then when I make a click at Soccer button, I can see all Country with this sport. But this array is so big and I need `limitTo` filter for max 10 country per Sport and when 'more button' is clicked I can increase the max in 10 per each click. I have an example in

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swxhu0w2/)

But the `limitTo` is not limiting as expected. How can I fix it?

**Update** the solution now is with `value.slice(stard,end)` I looking a method with limitTo, is because the array is unsorted, and no always have the required result.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `limitTo` filter needs an array to work.

You could use `toArray` filter from this [github repo](https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular-toArrayFilter).

The `$filter` calls in the controller could be moved back to markup that was just a test during finding the issue.

Below is the updated code with the `toArray` filter or in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/swxhu0w2/5/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",['angular.filter', 'angular-toArrayFilter']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',  function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.list = [{"sport":"Soccer","country":"Brazil","Teams":"TeamA vs Teamb"},
                   {"sport":"Baseball","country":"USA","Teams":"TeamA vs Teamb"},
                   {"sport":"Soccer","country":"USA","Teams":"TeamA vs Teamb"},
                   {"sport":"Baseball","country":"USA","Teams":"TeamA vs Teamb"},
                   {"sport":"Soccer","country":"Cuba","Teams":"TeamA vs Teamb"},
                   {"sport":"Baseball","country":"Brazil","Teams":"TeamA vs Teamb"},
                   {"sport":"Soccer","country":"Germany","Teams":"TeamA vs Teamb"},
                   {"sport":"Baseball","country":"Russia","Teams":"TeamA vs Teamb"},
                   {"sport":"Soccer","country":"USA","Teams":"TeamA vs Teamb"},
                   {"sport":"Soccer","country":"Spain","Teams":"TeamA vs Teamb"},
                   {"sport":"Soccer","country":"Brazil","Teams":"TeamA vs Teamb"} 
                  ];
    console.log($scope.list);
    
    $scope.sports = $filter('groupBy')($scope.list, 'sport');
    $scope.countries = $filter('groupBy')($scope.list, 'country');
    
    
});
```

```css
.country{
    margin-left:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/petebacondarwin/angular-toArrayFilter/master/toArrayFilter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.5/angular-filter.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in sports">
       {{key}}
        <div ng-repeat="countryObj in countries | toArray | limitTo:3">
            <span class="country">{{countryObj[0].country}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've added the `show more` button to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/swxhu0w2/6/).